# How to set Rails Cache log level separately?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, logging

I use a pretty old rails version which is 2.3.2 because of legacy project.

I set global log_level to :debug in our rails app. But since we also use Rails.cache the log file are full of annoying lines such as
Cache read: ...
Cache miss: ...

I want to just suppress these but not affect other 'more useful' info such as SQL logging.

How to do that?

Comment: And a more general question is how to tweak log level for a specific class in Rails? Is there an equivalent as log4j in Ruby/Rails world?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Well, after initializing your cache store (in the example below, I use memory store) in your specific environment.rb file, you can redirect cache_store's log to a separate file and also tweak the logger level:

```
config.cache_store = ActiveSupport::Cache::MemoryStore.new(:expires_in => 5.minutes)
config.cache_store.logger = Logger.new("#{Rails.root}/log/#{ENV['RAILS_ENV']}_cache.log")
config.cache_store.logger.level = Logger::INFO
```

In addition to that, the cache store has a method called silence! that will turn off the logger :-|

```
config.cache_store.silence!
```

Comment: The silence! is not available in old rails (my version is 2.3.2, and it's not there). But the first way save my ass! thanks.  
something strange is I must change  
`config.cache_store = :file_store, 'tmp/cache/aria'`  
to  
`config.cache_store = ActiveSupport::Cache::FileStore.new 'tmp/cache/aria'`  
and then add the other 2 lines.

Comment: you can do `Rails.cache.silence!` in `enviroment.rb`

Comment: This is now out of date for modern rails. One needs to set the cache log subscriber on ActiveSupport::Cache::Store.logger in an initializer or similar. Rails 3 and up does not log cache hits etc by default anymore.

Comment: `config.after_initialize do
    Rails.cache.silence!` worked for me for Rails 5.2

Comment: In rails 4.2 I get: undefined method `logger=' for #<Array:0x0000000346e968> (NoMethodError)