# How to get the cache misses in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am using `Rails.cache` for caching

```
config.action_controller.perform_caching = true
config.cache_store = :file_store, "location"
```

How can I check if there was a cache miss?

Also, I am not able to see the cache miss information in my logs.

Thanks

Comment: You can configure the log level for caching. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7254184/how-to-set-rails-cache-log-level-separately

Comment: @DanielWestendorf I looked at this post, it talks about setting a separate log level for caching because of too many logs. However, I am not able to view the logs from cache at all. Also my `config.log_level` is set to `debug` and also tried `info`

Comment: I'm pretty sure that cache logging is now silenced, unless explicitly enabled. I'm trying to find a source for that. Maybe try setting your caching log level to debug explicitly?

Comment: I tried setting it to debug explicitly but still could not turn on the caching logs

Answer (score 2):

To get pragmatic notifications about cache events, look to `ActiveSupport::Notifications` to subscribe to [cache events](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/20c91119903f70eb19aed33fe78417789dbf070f/activesupport/lib/active_support/cache.rb#L612).